# Replace laptop battery with lower mAh

Tags: battery, battery-life

My current laptop battery has a capacity of 2750 mAh. Will my laptop still work if I use a replacement battery with fewer mAh?

Comment: Your just going to reduce the amount of time you can run on battery power.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason the lower milli-Amp Hour (mAh) battery would not work so long as it is the correct shape and size for your laptop, and produces the correct amount of volts and watts for the system.

Think of mAh as relative length of time this battery can run your laptop for. So a lower value in this metric means your laptop will not run as long on that battery as it would on a battery with a higher mAh value.

Comment: In theory this is correct, but the cells itself are capable of some output current, and the manufacturer should respect this for specific laptop model by it's maximum power consumption. So you can actually damage (overheat, shorten lifespan, ...) battery meant for some lowpower ultrabook inside gaming laptop. Of course we have over-current-protections (OCP) almost everywhere today. But your answer is just too general in way "there is no reason.." thats not correct even if thats true in more than 99% of cases.

Comment: With the caveats I gave (size, shape (which basically accounts for whether the battery was designed for that laptop or not) and power requirements) the statement is correct. It could be a case of the user previously had an extended-life battery and now is looking at the "normal" battery for that system, which would be cheaper with the primary metric difference being in mAh. Limiting ourselves to that metric as OP did, we can assume all other factors are equal. If that is not the case, OP can and should clarify their question.

Comment: Too much assuming something, that he is _stupid_ enough, that he has some extended capacity and now looking for normal and so on. I just tried to clarify your general statement that fewer mAh only means less time on battery. Of course OP doesn't have to worry, if the battery is sold for his model and it's from trustworthy manufacturer, it's gonna be alright.